# spark scala code value inside map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
Scala> val custdata = sc.textFile("file:///stage/Sales/lego/test/new/spark_test/testing1.csv")
custdata: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = file:///stage/Sales/lego/test/new/spark_test/testing1.csv MapPartitionsRDD[8] at textFile at <console>:27

scala> custdata.collect
res3: Array[String] = Array(1,111,1000, 1,222,2000, 2,222,15000, 3,111,4500, 4,333,1200, 2,333,1000, 4,444,2000)

scala> val data= custdata.map(x=> { val b = x.split(",")})
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Unit] = MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at <console>:29

scala> data.collect
res4: Array[Unit] = Array((), (), (), (), (), (), ())
```

---

**spark scala doubt:** Because of  `val b` I am not able to get the  result ? guys could you please help me with it

Answer (score 4):

You are not returning any value in the `custdata.map(x=> { val b = x.split(",")})` if you just want to return b you can replace with  `custdata.map(x=> { val b = x.split(",");b})` or `custdata.map(x=> {  x.split(",")})` or even better (as @joelb correctly noted in a comment) `custdata.map(_.split(","))`